# Apple App Site Association (AASA) file is not being updated on app-site-association.cdn-apple.com

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, apple-app-site-association, aasa

My app has three separate environments named

1. int
2. sbx
3. prod

Here are my three AASA files on my webservers.

1. https://app.int.croissant.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
2. https://app.sbx.croissant.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
3. https://app.croissant.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

Here are the same three AASA files on Apple's CDN

1. https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/app.int.croissant.com
2. https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/app.sbx.croissant.com
3. https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/app.croissant.com

I have two questions.

1. How can I invalidate the Apple CDN so that my new AASA files are pulled in?
2. Do my new AASA files look like they will support all possible paths? Does * capture any path e.g., /collection/123, /wallet/oauth?code=123, /sign-in

I've done the generic Googling and docs reading around this. I can't seem to find anything specifically related to Apple's CDN.

Comment: You can't force the update. You have to wait for apple to refresh (this can be a few days from memory). You can configure developer mode in your info.plist to bypass the CDN for non-production domains

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 ... two questions.

1. I made the the updates to my ASAA 3 weeks ago. Any other ideas?
2. I'm using Expo and React-Native. Do you know if the bypass is possible there?

Comment: The developer mode is set in the [associated domains entitlement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_associated-domains) so it shouldn't matter which development environment you are using.

Comment: I pulled the various files you linked to and they were all the same, except I got a 404 on the https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/app.int.croissant.com url.

Comment: It seems like this issue is resolved with all the files being identical? How did this happen?

Comment: I updated my Cache-Control header for this file to no-cache and several days later they all matched up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating my AASA file's Cache-Control header to no-cache fixed this for me.

I use Next.js, so here is my next.config.js that fixed this for me.

```
 {
    source: "/.well-known/apple-app-site-association",
    headers: [
      { key: "Content-Type", value: "application/json" },
      { key: "Cache-Control", value: "no-cache" },
    ],
  },
```